# Screeps built-in functions don't return expected types

Tags: javascript, screeps

In the game [Screeps](https://screeps.com/), I'm having some issues with the return types of some of the built-in functions. Take the following code:

```
var creeps1 = Game.creeps
var room = Game.rooms[myRoomName];
var creeps2 = room.find(FIND_CREEPS);

console.log(creeps1.constructor.name);
console.log(creeps1 instanceof Array);

console.log(creeps2.constructor.name);
console.log(creeps2 instanceof Array);

console.log([].constructor.name);
console.log([] instanceof Array);
```

You'd expect these to all be arrays and so all be instances of `Array`. Yet in a world game I get the following results (with `myRoomName` set to the name of a room I have access to):

```
// Results in world
[1:11:11 AM] Object
[1:11:11 AM] false
[1:11:11 AM] Array
[1:11:11 AM] false
[1:11:11 AM] Array
[1:11:11 AM] true
```

But wait, it gets weirder. When I run the same code in the simulation (this time `myRoomName` is `'sim'`), I get the following results:

```
// Results in simulation
[1:11:11 AM] Object
[1:11:11 AM] false
[1:11:11 AM] Array
[1:11:11 AM] true
[1:11:11 AM] Array
[1:11:11 AM] true
```

Why aren't all these functions returning instances of `Array`? How are there even different versions of `Array` in the world environment? And is there a way to transform the results into instances of `Array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game.creeps doesn't return an array, it returns an object behaving as a hash where the creep name is the key and the creep is the value.  This is documented in the [API for Game.creeps](http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/articles/203016382-Game#creeps).  If you need this to be in an Array, you can iterate through the object and append the entries to an array.

As far as why creeps2 instanceof is different in the simulation vs the actual game, it's hard to tell.  However, Array.isArray(creeps2) seems to behave consistently between the two environments (returns true in both instances).